# What is "Common data service" app in the preinstalled app list?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

when I searched for installed app from setting>App then under ALL heading I found the "Commmon data service" app with unknown/suspicious icon.
is it a android pre-installed system app?
or something from unknown sources?
Device is: HTC Desire 620g, dual sim with Android version=kitkat 4.4.2, & Kernel version=3.4.67

pls help..

Comment: Since different phones come with different apps pre-installed, you'll need to [edit] your question to say what phone you have and whether you got it from a carrier.

Comment: Thank u Dan for the reply, I should have added the device details earlier, however let me know if this particular app is from Android system installation or from HTC. Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a program that enables the device to access data from one app while using another. Like an internal search engine as it were... I'd leave well alone....

Comment: Yes I also think so but the main concern is whether this app is a part of Android system or OEM or installed separately from any unknown third party..., thanks,

Comment: You say "seems to be". What information is this based on?